# jQuery POST request getting 403 response

Tags: jquery, http-headers, http-status-code-403

I have a form on `index.php` that is sends a POST request (via jQuery) to `writer.php` on my server.  This file should then append the POSTed data to `logs.json`.  But the server is responding to the request for `writer.php` with `403 forbidden`.

I can surf to `writer.php` no problem.  I've tried setting the permissions of both `writer.php` and `logs.json` to 777 but still get 403 back.  Both files have the same Owner/Group as all the other files in the directory.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        data: "data goes here"
      },
      dataType: "text",
      url: "writer.php",
      success: function success(json) {
        //...
      },
      error: function error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
      }
    });
```

and writer.php:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["data"])){
    $fp = fopen("logs.json", "w+");
    fwrite($fp, $_POST["data"]);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted my web host and they fixed it.  The cause was:

> a false positive mod_security rule which was causing this behavior